# How to find position of User in query?

Tags: sqlalchemy

How to find position of User in query ?
I have ( I am using MySQL)

```
session.query(UserModel).order_by(desc(UserModel.age)).all()
```

and I have user id, how to find position of that specific id is ordered array ?
( I can return all and iterate but is there uicker way to solve this on database level, need to run fast)

Answer (score 2):

Database should support [window functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_%28SQL%29) to do this. Raw SQL query will look like this:

```
SELECT pos FROM
    (SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY age DESC) AS pos FROM user) AS sub
    WHERE sub.id = :id;
```

In SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import func, desc

user_id = 42
sub = (session
    .query(
        UserModel.id,
        func.row_number().over(order_by=desc(UserModel.age)).label('pos'))
    .subquery())
pos = session.query(sub.c.pos).filter(sub.c.id==user_id).scalar()
```

Note that returned index is 1-based.

Among popular RDBMS this will work in PostgreSQL, Oracle, MSSQL, but not in MySQL or SQLite.

Comment: How about MySQL or SQLite Databases? Are there any solutions on them?